# Decomposition of hermitian form used in the definition of Griffiths/Nakano positivity

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry

Let $E$ be a hermitian holomorphic vector bundle over a complex manifold $X$. Then $\Theta(E)$, the curvature of $E$, is a section of $\bigwedge^{1,1}X\otimes\operatorname{End}(E)$. However, we have the following isomorphism: $$\bigwedge\nolimits^{\!1,1}X\otimes\operatorname{End}(E) \cong \left(T^{1,0}X\otimes E\otimes\overline{T^{1,0}X\otimes E}\right)^*.$$ Under this isomorphism, $\Theta(E)$ corresponds to a hermitian form $\theta_E$ on $T^{1,0}X\otimes E$. This is used to define Griffiths and Nakano positivity of $E$.

Now suppose $E$ and $F$ are two hermitian holomorphic vector bundles over $X$. The curvature satisfies $\Theta(E\otimes F) = \Theta(E)\otimes\operatorname{id}_F + \operatorname{id}_E\otimes\Theta(F)$.

> Is there a similar decomposition for $\theta_{E\otimes F}$ under the above isomorphism? If not, what about the case where $F$ is a line bundle?

I've been playing around with tensor products for a while now but I can't seem to get it straight.

Comment: It is not clear to me which kind of decomposition you are looking for.
The curvature of $E\otimes F$ gives an hermitian form on $T_X\otimes E\otimes F$, but this you know. How do you want to decompose this latter tensor product?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your notations, the hermitian form $\theta_E$ on $T_X\otimes E$ defined by $\Theta_E$ is given in a somewhat more extrinsic way by
$$
\theta_E(v\otimes\sigma,v\otimes\sigma):=h(\Theta_E(v,\bar v)\cdot \sigma,\sigma), 
$$ 
where

- $h$ is the hermitian metric on $E$,
- $v\in T_X$, so that $\bar v\in \overline{T_X}$ (or, if you want, $v\in T^{1,0}_X$ so that $\bar v\in T^{0,1}_X$),
- $\sigma\in E$.

Note that I gave the formula just for decomposable (rank one) tensors, but then you extend it to all tensors by sesquilinearity.

Now, let $(E,h_E)$ and $(F,h_F)$ be two holomorphic hermitian vector bundles. Take the product metric $h_{E\otimes F}=h_{E}\otimes h_F$ on their tensor product so that, as you said, the curvature of the corresponding Chern connection is given by
$$
\Theta(E\otimes F)=\Theta(E)\otimes\operatorname{Id}_F+\operatorname{Id}_E\otimes\Theta(F).
$$
Then, for $v\in T_X$, $\sigma\in E$ and $\tau\in F$, you get
$$
\begin{aligned}
\theta_{E\otimes F}(v\otimes\sigma\otimes\tau,v\otimes\sigma\otimes\tau) &=
h_{E\otimes F}(\Theta_{E\otimes F}(v,\bar v)\cdot(\sigma\otimes\tau),\sigma\otimes\tau) \\
&=h_{E\otimes F}((\Theta(E)(v,\bar v)\otimes\operatorname{Id}_F \\
&\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad+\operatorname{Id}_E\otimes \Theta(F)(v,\bar v))\cdot(\sigma\otimes\tau),\sigma\otimes\tau) \\
&=h_{E\otimes F}((\Theta(E)(v,\bar v)\cdot\sigma)\otimes\tau+\sigma\otimes(\Theta(F)(v,\bar v)\cdot\tau),\sigma\otimes\tau) \\
&=h_{E\otimes F}((\Theta(E)(v,\bar v)\cdot\sigma)\otimes\tau,\sigma\otimes\tau) \\
&\qquad+h_{E\otimes F}(\sigma\otimes(\Theta(F)(v,\bar v)\cdot\tau),\sigma\otimes\tau) \\
&=h_E(\Theta(E)(v,\bar v)\cdot\sigma,\sigma)h_F(\tau,\tau) \\
&\qquad+h_E(\sigma,\sigma)h_F(\Theta(F)(v,\bar v)\cdot\tau,\tau) \\
&=\theta_E(v\otimes\sigma,v\otimes\sigma)h_F(\tau,\tau)+h_E(\sigma,\sigma)\theta_F(v\otimes\tau,v\otimes\tau).
\end{aligned}
$$
Thus, the decomposition you were looking for is perhaps the most natural one:
$$
\theta_{E\otimes F}=\theta_E\otimes h_F+h_E\otimes\theta_F.
$$

**EDIT:** Re-edited the answer coherently with [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/134232/local-expression-involved-in-the-definition-of-positivity-of-vector-bundles/134569#134569) other answer.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, you can use this decomposition to show that for any hermitian holomorphic vector bundle $E$ on a compact complex manifold with a positive line bundle $L$ (so it is algebraic by the Kodaira Embedding Theorem), there is some $k_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $E\otimes L^k$ is Griffiths positive for all $k \geq k_0$.

Comment: More than this, you can use it to show that it is Nakano positive!

Comment: Of course. Is there a slick way to see this? At the moment I'm using Cauchy-Schwarz and an operator norm, then by compactness, all the relative terms are bounded. Finally, as $\theta_{L^k} = k\theta_L$, it is just a matter of choosing $k$ large enough. It is precisely how Serre's Theorem is proved in Huybrechts' *Complex Geometry*, except there is no mention of $\theta_E$, but rather the endomorphism $[i\Theta(E), \Lambda] : \bigwedge^{p,q}X\otimes E \to \bigwedge^{p,q}X\otimes E$. Do you know if there is some direct relationship between $\theta_E$ and $[i\Theta(E), \Lambda]$?

Comment: What do you mean? The former is an hermitian form, the latter an operator acting on forms...

Comment: I suppose I was wondering about the map $\theta_E$ and the map $h_E([i\Theta(E), \Lambda]\cdot,\cdot)$, but the latter does not take a tangent vector as an input.

Comment: Does the expression of $\theta_E$ you've written agree with the one stated in Chapter VII, section 6 of Demailly's book? I don't think he includes the factor of $i$, but I may be mistaken.

Comment: Either way, do you have a reference which uses this expression for $\theta_E$?

Comment: My expression of $\theta_E$ of course agrees with the one in Demailly's book. It's just a coordinate-free way to write it. Try to write it down in a orthonormal frame and it will be clear!

Comment: If $i\Theta(E) = ic_{jk\lambda\mu} dz_j\wedge d\bar{z}_k\otimes e_{\lambda}^*\otimes e_{\mu}$ as in Demailly's book (page 338, equation 6.1) then $h(i\Theta(E)(v,\bar{v})\cdot\sigma, \sigma) = h(ic_{jk\lambda\mu} v_j\bar{v_k}\sigma_{\lambda}e_{\mu}, \sigma) = ic_{jk\lambda\mu} v_j\bar{v_k}\sigma_{\lambda}h(e_{\mu}, \sigma) = ic_{jk\lambda\mu} v_j\bar{v_k}\sigma_{\lambda}\bar{\sigma_{\mu}}$ which has a factor of $i$ that isn't present in Demailly's local expression for $\theta_E$ (page 338, equation 6.2). What am I missing?

Comment: I have asked another question which will hopefully clear things up for me: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/134232/local-expression-involved-in-the-definition-of-positivity-of-vector-bundles

Comment: I am sorry I didn't have much time during the last days. I'll give you the answer later today!

Comment: Do you know of a reference which proves that $E\otimes L^k$ is Nakano positive for $k$ large enough ($X$ compact, $L$ positive)? I thought I could prove it, but I keep getting stuck.